# CGAL Triangulated Surface Mesh Shortest Paths algorithm - assertion errors

Tags: c++, cgal

I am experimenting with the [Triangulated Surface Mesh Shortest Paths](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/index.html#title23) algorithm of the CGAL library.
I'm using the following triangulated square case for testing purposes:
[image]

When I try to compute the shortest distance between any two vertices I always get one of the following two errors:

error1:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of  'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: baseOrientation != CGAL::COLLINEAR
File: /usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/function_objects.h  
Line: 588
```

error 2:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: _idx < data_.size()
File: /usr/local/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/Properties.h
Line: 204
```

You can download the minimal code example including the mesh in off format [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rwt4h89hbbkhyy/cgal_discrete_geodesics_minimal_example.tar.gz?dl=0). I followed the implementation shown on the CGAL site. Compilation requires the CGAL and gmp libraries:

```
g++ main.cpp -lCGAL -lgmp
```

The executable requires two arguments: the indices of the source and target point:

```
a.out 2 6
```

Try 2 and 6 to get the first error, or 0 and 2 to get the second error.

Comment: You have to use `-frounding-math` with g++ but there were indeed some bugs that I fixed [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3977).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I cloned your branch (`SMSP-fix_border_vertices`, latest commit `13751fe`). Then i compiled it with cmake (`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../path_to_source`) and make. Also, I compiled the test code with `-frounding-math`. But I still get the same errors.

Comment: In the assertion "error1", is the file pointed the new one? It is surprizing you still have the same error.

Comment: Just recompiled CGAL again with the updated sources. Im sure im not using the original sources if its that what you mean.

Comment: I've added [this example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3977/files#diff-7263b7790fe52042fbcf95531bd81f56) which AFAIU is the test you described and it worked for me. What did not work for you? We can move the discussion in the ticket directly.

Comment: Hello, I just noticed that the error indeed pointed to a different file from an older installation. The errors were gone after removing it. Your code also works for me, thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: @sloriot: I have done some more testing and encountered situation on a simple geometry where the shortest path algorithm returns an inconsistent result. Especially a query with target and source point exchanged results in different distances. I've collected the material [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k914a3vefvafr7o/cgal_discrete_geodesics_minimal_example2.tar.gz?dl=0). Try 4 and 11 as arguments.

Comment: Do you mind opening an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues)? It is easier to track for me. Thanks.

Comment: Opened the [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/3993) on github.